# Pointer To Structure: Understanding Element Addressing

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, pool

So I have this structure:

```
typedef struct my_structure_s{
    uint32_t* label;
    uint32_t* data_1;
    uint32_t* data_2;
} my_structure_t;
```

Ultimately, I am working towards allocating a single large block of memory, and moving the pointers to point towards appropriate places in the large block of memory. This block will be big enough so that I can have room for N1 and N2 elements for data_1 and data_2, where N1 and N2 are calculated in the program.

Actually, I am going to have a few of these structures, and I want to eventually point all of them to proper places in this block. I know how to move the pointers to point to the correct places, but I am having trouble understanding where the inner pointers get created in memory.

For instance I define:

```
my_structure_t* my_struct = malloc( sizeof(my_struct) );
my_structure_t example_struct;
my_struct = &example_struct;
```

Now I want to see the relative addresses, so I write:

```
printf("Base Address: %p\n", &my_struct);
printf("First Element: %p\n", &(my_struct->label));
printf("Difference: %x\n\n", (uint32_t)&(my_struct->label) - (uint32_t)&my_struct);
```

For some reason, the difference is a negative value! Why? Yes I am using a 32 bit kernel. Shouldn't the first element be next to, but further down, the heap? Also, why is the memory difference not 0x4 but instead -0x8? I think everything should be aligned...seeing how its a structure of repetitions of the same data type...and that data type has a sizeof() of 4.

Second, what if I don't point the pointer to an instance of a structure? Eg what if I do:

```
my_structure_t* my_struct_2;
my_structure_t* big_pool =  malloc( sizeof(my_structure_t) );
my_struct_2 = big_pool;    

printf("Base Address: %p\n", &my_struct_2);
printf("First Element: %p\n", &(my_struct_2->label));
printf("Difference: %x\n",  (uint32_t)&(my_struct_2->label) - (uint32_t)&my_struct_2);
```

Here, the values are totally wacky. Once, I got a difference of 0x49f02aac. Where then is the  actual label pointer placed in memory? In this case, how can I make sure the address of the label pointer itself is right after the base address, without pointing the base pointer to a normal structure instance? Can it be assigned somehow?

Ie, if I were to point the label pointer somewhere after creating the structure pointer, where would the label pointer itself be stored? How can I make sure that all of these inner pointers get stored, in the same sequence as in the definition, right after the base pointer?

Yes yes, I could have possible defined data_1[MAX_N1] or some other work around like that, then just defined an array of structure pointers, and assigned each one a fixed memory size, but I didn't. There are various reasons. Please stick with the questions I am asking.

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: That cast from a memory address to `uint32_t` is a bad idea, in particularly under 64-bit systems, and it makes your code unportable.

Comment: Barak -- Yes I know, but I am just doing this to try and understand things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `malloc()` do not allocate pointers, it allocates memory for your struct, and then it returns a pointer to it. It is perfectly possible to have an uninitialized pointer, or a pointer pointing nowhere (`NULL`).

Second, in C there are three types of variables, regarding to allocation:

1. Static variables (globals). They exist all the time the program is running.
2. Automatic variables (locals). They exist as long as the code block containing them is running.
3. Dynamic variables (malloc). They exists until they are freed.

With that in mind your examples:

```
my_structure_t* my_struct = malloc( sizeof(my_struct) );
my_structure_t example_struct;
my_struct = &example_struct;
```

The first structure is dynamic, the second one is automatic. Then you make the pointer point to the automatic one. Remember, you can have pointers to anything. The dynamic variable is lost (leaked).

```
printf("Base Address: %p\n", &my_struct);
printf("First Element: %p\n", &(my_struct->label));
```

That is tricky: `my_struct` is a pointer, but you are getting its address, so what you get is the address of the automatic variable `my_struct` of type pointer.

The -8 happens because you are comparing the addresses of two local variables: the local pointer `my_struct` and the member `label` of the local structure variable `example_struct`. And those just happen to be so layout in memory.

Try instead:

```
printf("Base Address: %p\n", (void*)my_struct);
printf("First Element: %p\n", (void*)&(my_struct->label));
```

(BTW: it is always a good idea to cast to `(void*)` when `printf("%p")`.

The other example has a similar error: do print the address of the structure or the value of the pointer, but not the address of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`my_struct` is a pointer to a `my_structure_t`.  There are no guarantees about where the *pointer* is in relation to the object it points to.

I beleive what you are trying to test, based on your comments about the memory location is

```
printf("Base Address: %p\n", my_struct);
printf("First Element: %p\n", &(my_struct->label));
printf("Difference: %x\n\n", (uint32_t)&(my_struct->label) - (uint32_t)my_struct)
```

Notice the removal of `&` before `my_struct` in 2 places compared to your code.

In answer to the actual question you asked

> Also, why is the memory difference not 0x4 but instead -0x8?

Either `sizeof(my_structure_t*)` is 8, or the compiler decided that `example_struct` should be 8 byte aligned, and added padding when adding thee variables to your stack.